# Show 'mail sent' message to user after mailitem.send()

Tags: vb.net, email, outlook-addin

I'm writing an addin with VB that sends an email and I want to show them a 'Email sent successfully' messagebox after mailitem.send() method completes successfully.  mailitem.send() doesn't produce a value, so I can't do something like:

```
if mailitem.send() then
   messagebox.show("Email sent successfully")
end if
```

How would I show a messagebox confirming the sending of the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an error, Send will raise an exception. If it does not, you can assume the message was successfully handed over to the transport provider

Submission is asynchronous, so the actual delivery will occur later (sometimes much later, e.g. if you do not have a network connection at the time Send is called).

You can install an event sink on the Items collection of the Sent Items folder and show the message box when the Items.ItemAdd event fires.

Comment: so I can do something like

    try
       mailitem.send()
       messagebox.show("Fax Sent")
    catch ex as exception
       messagebox.show(ex.message)
    end try

that seems easy enough

Comment: That should work, but there is no guarantee that the message will be delivered. It only means that all recipients were resolved and Outlook was able to hand it to a transport provider.

Comment: That's good enough to ship.  I can add the better checking in an update.  Thanks again Dmitry